# How can I push a result of entries/products from a loop into an array?

Tags: templating

In the grand scheme, I am trying to get all products that are *not* related to specific categories.

Since any product can belong to any given number of categories, I am trying to loop through all categories and then only query against the categories that I want.

This is what I have so far:

```
{% set excludeCategoryIds = [36, 44] %}
{% set allProducts = craft.commerce.products.type('myType').order('title asc') %}
{% set products = [] %}

{% for category in craft.categories.group('myCategories').relatedTo(allProducts) %}
    {% if category.id not in excludeCategoryIds %}
        {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}

        {# push entires into products?? #}
        {% set products = products|merge([entries]) %} {# doesn't work #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Once all products are found, then I'll loop through them.

```
{% if products|length %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

I could also loop through each of the entires as [described in the docs](https://craftcms.com/support/entries-related-to-category) but it's starting to feel like this is getting out of control.

Is there a better way to only show products that are not related to specific categories?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't return an array of items; it returns an ElementCriteriaModel:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}
```

That's probably why you're having problems with the `|merge`.

Changing it to the following should do the trick:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).find() %}
```